# Prove this set is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Consider a point $\vec{z}=(z_1, ..., z_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $B_{r_i}(z_i)$ be an open ball about $z_i$ of radius $r_i$, for $1\le r_i \le n$, so that $B_{r_i}(z_i)$ is in $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the subset $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, with $U:=(x_1,...,x_n):x_i\in B_{r_i}(z_i)$. Show that $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My approach:

Consider an arbitrary point $\vec{x}\in U$. Every $x_i$ of $\vec{x}$ is in $B_{r_i}(z_i)$. Take $r:=\min\{r_i\}$, then $x_i\in B_r(z_i)\subseteq B_{r_i}(z_i)$. *This implies that $\vec{x}\in B_r(\vec{z})\subseteq U$. Hence, $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.*

I would appreciate your opinion, since I'm not very certain about the italicized part of the proof. Do you think it's rigorous enough?

Comment: I think the logic is fine.

Comment: Let $z=(0,0), r_1=1, r_2=100, x=(10,10)$ ,then $r=1$ and $x\in U$, but $x_2=10\notin  B_r(z_i)=B_1(0)$.

Comment: @yoyo: does it look like the case of $\vec{0}$ is a very special case that needs to be considered separately, with the proof working for the rest of the points?

Comment: oh~~Do you means "for all $i$ " in the definition of $U$?
If so, then I am wrong and you're right ~~because I thought it means "there exist $i$ "

Comment: Note that the computation of $r$ must take the value of $x$ into account, if $x$ is near the boundary, then $r$ must get smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful with your choice of radius and you need to be explicit
about what norm you are using. The $\sup $ norm $\|x\|_\infty = \max_i |x_i|$
is the most convenient here.

If $x \in U$, let $\rho = \min_i (x_i-(z_i-r_i), (z_i+r_i)-x_i)$ (remember
that $x_i \in (z_i-r_i, z_i+r_i)$ and note that $\rho >0$.

Then $B_\infty(x,\rho) \subset U$.

If you prefer the Euclidean norm, note that $\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_2$ and
so $B_2(x,\rho) \subset B_\infty(x,\rho)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=(x_1,..,x_n)\in U$ then for each $i$ we have $|x_i-z_i|<r_i$ so  we can take  $s_i>0$ such that $(x_i-s_i,x_i+s_i)\subset (z_i-r_i,z_i+r_i).$ Let $s=\min (s_1,..,s_n).$ Let $J_i=(x_i-s,x_i+s).$ With respect to the Euclideam metric $d$ we have $B_d(x,s)\subset \prod_{i=1}^nJ_i\subset U.$

Notation: $B_d(x,s)=\{y:d(y,x)<s\}.$